Movie about human and alien fighter pilots
Trying to remember a movie from the 80s that depicts:

humans fighting against aliens spacecrafts 
one of the human pilots crashes on the planet along with the enemy alien pilot 
they become friends(?) 
the planet has meteor showers 
the planet has underground    monsters with long tongues/tentacles 
the alien pilot dies in the end


Sounds like Enemy Mine. From the wiki:

It starred Dennis Quaid [Willis E. Davidge] and Louis Gossett, Jr. [Jeriba Shigan] as a human and alien
  soldier, respectively, who become stranded together on an inhospitable
  planet and must overcome their mutual distrust in order to cooperate
  and survive.

Also from the wiki:

...After initial hostilities, the two eventually learn to cooperate to
  survive. They work together to build a shelter for protection against meteorite storms, a natural phenomenon that periodically strikes the planet.
...A blizzard and an attack by an indigenous predator forces Davidge and Jeriba to flee their shelter...
...Jeriba later slowly dies in childbirth, but not before making Davidge
  swear to take the child back to the Drac homeworld and recite his full
  ancestry, so that he can join Drac society...


You can check parts of it on YouTube (the parts that haven't been removed):




That's the one! Thanks!

I can't believe it...I've never seen this movie, but I knew it immediately from the description.
